# RabbitMQ change main password for kubernetes installation

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have installed rabbitmq on kubernetes. I accidentally gave a blank master password when installing rabbitmq. How do i update the master password?
I am not able to login to rabbitmq console with blank password

I used this instructions to install rabbitmq on gke
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/rabbitmq/README.md

Comment: Check the config map, it might have the password. Another option is to delete the installation and install again with correct environment variables

Comment: I tried to exec into the pod and use rabbitmqctl to update the password and it worked. But i am curios to know if it updates the k8s secret or not where the password is stored.

Comment: It must be in a secret or configmap, but im not quite sure how google install those kinds of aplications. It is probably with helm charts so you could check with a kubectl get all and see what it created and check

Answer (score 0):

exec into the pod
Use rabbitmqctl to update the password